1 year traveling Europe- EU Citizen and non-EU Spouse-- possible
I have an Irish passport. My spouse has a Canadian passport (non-EU). We want to spend a year traveling around Europe. We won't be in any country for more than a month or two. My non-EU spouse would enter on a 90 day schengen visa with me. Would this be a problem? Meaning, would they have trouble because they are a visa overstayer?
Any one have any similar experience with this? Specifically the non-EU spouse stays longer than 90 days and doesn't get a residency card from any EU country. What happens? Is this a problem?

This should not be a problem, we already have a bunch of questions on this e.g. https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/183107/non-eu-spouse-travelling-with-eu-spouse-in-schengen-area-time-restrictions and https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/98037/can-a-non-eu-spouse-of-eu-citizen-not-resident-in-eu-travel-in-the-eu-more-than

If you want to be safe, bring a copy of your marriage certificate.  My experience and that of my parents suggests that in most countries you're almost certainly not going to need it, but I can't speak to the practices of every country.
